# Total number of lines and words in a file

Tags: python, list, word-count, line-count

I have an exercise that is asking to calculate the number of lines and words in an email file, excluding the subject line.

I can get the total number of lines and words with the following code:

```
file = "email.txt" 
num_lines = 0
num_words = 0
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split() 
        if not line.startswith ('Subject'):
                num_lines += 1
                num_words += len(words)
        
print(num_lines)
print(num_words)
```

I would like to define a function to get the same information however, the second function for the word count is not return the desired value.

```
textFile = "email.txt"

def count_lines():
    with open (textFile, 'r') as file:
        num_lines = 0
        for line in file:
            words = line.split()
            if not line.startswith ('Subject'):
                num_lines = num_lines + 1
        return num_lines

def count_words():
    with open (textFile, 'r') as file:
        num_words = 0
        for words in file:
            words = line.split()
            if not line.startswith ('Subject'):
                num_words = num_words + 1
        return num_words

print(count_lines())
print(count_words())
```

Comment: `num_words += len(words)`.

Comment: `count_lines()` and `count_words()` are identical. How do you expect to get different output?

Comment: @ Gabip so how should the count_words() be modified?

Comment: instead of `num_words = num_words + 1` you should have  `num_words += len(words)`

Comment: Thank you ekhuomoro and Gabip. That helped however the count of words is different between the function code and the first code. in the first code i get 90 words and in the function option i get 30. shouldn't the result be the same? any way of testing which one is correct?

Comment: The `count_words` should not work. You use there `line` without defining it.
Are you sure that this is your real code?

Comment: yes, that's the real code, which may be written incorrectly

Comment: @lois so it shouldn't work at all but throw `NameError: name 'line' is not defined`. Please check my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you another solution, using list comprehension:

```
with open(textFile, 'r') as f:
    words_per_line = [len(line.split()) for line in f.readlines() if not line.startswith('Subject')]
    total_lines = len(words_per_line)
    total_words = sum(words_per_line)
```

Where `words_per_line` contains number of words per line in your file so if you count it (`len`) you will get the number of lines and if you `sum` it, you will get the total number of words.

Comment: thank you Gabip.  the list comprehension gives the same count the first code.